# How Do I Use a URL Parameter twice for SQL Queries in two asp.DataLists on one Page?

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, select

No matter what I've tried, I cannot get one query to work. I need to query the SQL Server database twice, because I need the album name (URL Parameter) listed under the Album heading. And I need song information listed under the Songs heading.

Here is the code where I use `Album` in the `WHERE` clause of the two DataLists and their datasources. The second `WHERE` clause causes an error.

```
<h2 class="w3-container" style="color:blue;">Album</h2>

<strong><p class="w3-container" id="albumParam" ></p></strong>

<script>
    type = "text/javascript"
    document.getElementById("albumParam").innerHTML = location.search.substring(1).substring(6, 150).replaceAll("+", " ").replaceAll("%2f", "/").replace("%26", "&").replaceAll("%2b", "+").replace("%2c", ",").replaceAll("%27", "'");
</script>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceAlbum" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FMConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Album FROM dbo.c_mymusic_songs WHERE (Album = @Album) ORDER BY Track"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DataList class="w3-container" ID="DataListAlbum" CellSpacing="3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceAlbum" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkAlbum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Album") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<strong><p class="w3-container" id="AlbumParam" ></p></strong>

<h2 class="w3-container" style="color:blue;">Songs</h2>

<script>
    type = "text/javascript"
    document.getElementById("Param").innerHTML = location.search.substring(1).substring(6, 150).replaceAll("+", " ").replaceAll("%2f", "/").replace("%26", "&").replaceAll("%2b", "+").replace("%2c", ",").replaceAll("%27", "'");
</script>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSongs" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FMConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Artist, Album, Track, Title FROM dbo.c_mymusic_songs WHERE (Album = @Album) ORDER BY Track">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="Album" Type="string" DefaultValue=" " />
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DataList ID="DataListSongs" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSongs" RepeatColumns="3"  
    CellSpacing="3" RepeatLayout="Table">  
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <table class="table">  
            <tr>  
                <td>  
                    <%# Eval("Track") %><br />  
                </td>  
                <td>  
                    <%# Eval("Title")%>  
                </td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:DataList>
```

The first query works but the 2nd select `where` clause causes this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> Must declare the scalar variable "@Album".

If I take out the `WHERE` clause in the second select query, I get all songs of course. But I need the `WHERE` clause.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSongs" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FMConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Artist, Album, Track, Title FROM dbo.c_mymusic_songs ORDER BY Track">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How can I define the scalar variable so that the second `WHERE` works and there is no error so that I can display only the songs for the url album parameter?

Comment: Here is the code behind:        
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string _Album = Request.QueryString.ToString();
            SqlDataSourceAlbum.SelectParameters.Add("Album", _Album);
        }

Comment: You need to declare `SelectParameters` a second time

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't your `Request.QueryString` have to have an index?  For instance `Request.QueryString["Album"].ToString()`

Also looks like you're missing this section (within `<asp:SqlDataSource/>`):

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Album" DbType = "String" Direction = "Input" QueryStringField="Album" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Lastly, I'm not sure if it impacts your display, but I think your `RepeatColumns="3"` is off compared to what you desire to show, which is only 2 columns (`Track`,`Title`). (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/datalist-control-in-Asp-Net-part-23/)

Here's a full example I found:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-SqlDataSource-pass-value-to-SelectParameter-using-QueryString-Parameter-Example.aspx.  (It's VB but should accomplish the same I sure).

Comment: I'm not using Request.QueryString. Where would I put that in the code?

Comment: The RepeatColumns="3" is correct, it wraps one column into 3 columns. I see now that I do have the RequestQueryString in the code behind. As far as the Request.QueryString goes, it works fine with the first query. I will try it though. The link you sent makes sense as an example. But I've already got the first query working. The example doesn't work for a datalist though.

Comment: <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Album" QueryStringField="Album" DbType="string"/>
        </SelectParameters> I tried this and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing the 'SelectParameters' element in the second datasource? -- without diving in too deep, that's the big difference I see between those 2 data sources.

Comment: Yes, it works the same with or without. I added thinking the parameter @Album would be declared. But it doesn't have an effect either way.